# How to add newline character in app.config?

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm not getting as how to write a message in app.config which consists of two or more lines.
My usual code in config file is :

```
add key="msg_test" value="This is test message."
```

And I read it in c sharp code like :

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[msg_test];
```

And I want to write something like

```
add key="msg_test" 
    value="This is test message \n are you sure you want to continue?"
```

Comment: why is it not working? what happends and what are you expecting? do you mean you put `\n` on the value string?

Comment: tried `"first line" +  Environment.NewLine + "second line"`?

Comment: @Reniuz: You can't write C# code in the config file.

Comment: @Guffa oh I get it. I thought that OP trying to add value programmatically.

Comment: If I put \n in the value string it prints \n instead of going to new line.
@Reniuz : Guffa is onto it. I want to know if there is a way to do this in app.config so that i can take that string as it is and use in my c# code

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just use line breaks in the value:

```
add key="msg_test" value="This is
test message."
```

You can also use XML encoded characters:

```
add key="msg_test" value="This is&#13;&#10;test message."
```

(I have tested both, and they work.)

Comment: I really did not think as it would be as straight forward as 1st answer.
And I was trying using XML encoded characters but somewhere I found #92 for \ and #110 for n. And these were not working.
Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @parixit: Using `#&92;#&110;` would indeed get you `\n` in the string, but that doesn't produce a single control character as in a literal string, it's just two separate characters.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa, your solution of using XML encoded (&#13;&#10;) saved me..!!

Answer (score 14):

The XML escape for newline is `&#xA;`, so this should work:

```
<add key="msg_test" 
value="This is test message &#xA; are you sure you want to continue?">
```

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, in Properties / Settings, in the string setting, click the drop down arrow, enter first line of text, press <kbd>Shift-Enter</kbd>, enter second line of text.

[image]